# Counting Text Channels, Voice Channels, All Channels and Roles

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
case 'sinfo':
const sinfo = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.addField('Server Name  :', message.guild.name)
.setTitle('Server Information ')
.addField('Server Owner  :', message.guild.owner.user.tag)
.addField('Members  :', message.guild.memberCount)
.addField('Text Channels  :', )
.addField('Voice Channels  :', )
.addField('All channels',)
.addField('Roles')
.addField('Region :', "")
.addField('Created At ⚙️ :', 'Sat Jan 27 2018 12:04:06')
.setFooter('For more commands check text channel ❕commands❕')
.setColor(0xF8F8F8)
.setThumbnail(message.guild.displayAvatarURL)
message.channel.send(sinfo);
```

I would need help with counting roles, text channels, voice channels and all channels. Automatic region would be apriciated aswell but its not necessary. I've serched on internet but I coudnt find it. The only one i could find was 2 years old...If its not possible just tell me I have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get collection of channels, do `guild.channels.cache`. From this point, you can just get its length. For roles, do the same. And finally for text/voice channels, filter the all channels collection (via `.filter()` function).

Comment: thanks, i get the point, could you please send me the four codes it would be much easier for me thx

Comment: i tried some commands myself but i keep making something wrong...

Comment: do you have an idea @David Buck ?

Comment: var channels = message.guild.channels.cache.length;
var roless = message.guild.roles.cache.length;
var textChannels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == "text").length;
var textChannels = message.guild.channels.cache.filter(channel => channel.type == "voice").length;